# How do I make a string validator for Deterministic Finite Automata?

Tags: javascript, finite-automata, deterministic

The regular expression for the DFA that I need to validate a string with is (bab | bbb) (a* b*) (a* | b*) (ba)* (aba) (bab | aba)* bb (a | b)* (bab | aba) (a | b)*

I thought of using transitions to tell when an inputted string is valid or not:

```
class DFA_Exp1 {
    constructor() {
      // Define the transitions as an object
      this.transitions = {
        0: { a: "invalid", b: 1 },
        1: { a: 2, b: 2 },
        2: { a: "invalid", b: 3 },
        3: { a: 4, b: 5 },
        4: { a: 4, b: 6 },
        5: { a: 7, b: 5 },
        6: { a: 7, b: 5 },
        7: { a: 9, b: 8 },
        8: { a: 11, b: 12 },
        9: { a: "invalid", b: 10 },
        10: { a: 7, b: "invalid" },
        11: { a: "invalid", b: 7 },
        12: { a: 13, b: 15 },
        13: { a: "invalid", b: 14 },
        14: { a: 17, b: "invalid" },
        15: { a: 16, b: "invalid" },
        16: { a: "invalid", b: 17 },
        17: { a: 17, b: 17 },
        "invalid": { a: "invalid", b: "invalid" },
      };
  
      this.acceptingState = 17;
    }

    validateInput(input) {
        let currentState = 0; // Initial state
    
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          const symbol = input[i];
    
          if (!this.transitions[currentState]) {
            return "invalid";
          }
    
          currentState = this.transitions[currentState][symbol];
    
          if (currentState === "invalid" || currentState === undefined) {
            return "invalid";
          }
        }

        if (currentState === this.acceptingState) {
            return "valid";
        }
        console.log(currentState);
        return "invalid";
        
    }  
}
```

It seems that I lack the knowledge of how to make transitions work because the currentState is always 0 and the string is always checked as invalid.

Is there a better way to do string validation or did I do something wrong with my validateInput method?

(I am very new to JavaScript and automata theory)

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not validating the regex directly? I mean, you have the regex ready and all, why not check if the string validates against it?

Comment: Is there a way to do that? I'm sorry, I'm not aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use the regex to validate the string:

```
const input = "bab";
const dfa_regex = /^(bab | bbb) (a* b*) (a* | b*) (ba)* (aba) (bab | aba)* bb (a | b)* (bab | aba) (a | b)*$/;
dfa_regex.exec(input);
```

I have used the syntax with /s to define the regex, but it may be counter intuitive at first. You can also use the constructor (which is the same in the end, just more explicit)

```
const dfa_regex = new RegExp("^(bab | bbb) (a* b*) (a* | b*) (ba)* (aba) (bab | aba)* bb (a | b)* (bab | aba) (a | b)*$");
```

Comment: I did not know that was possible, thank you! But is there a way for it to return valid or invalid?

Comment: exec will return null when not valid, if it is valid it will provide information about the match. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: It looks like it's always returning null. Even when I input a string like "babababbaba" which should be valid, I believe.

Comment: Now I did not challenge the regex... Play with it here https://regex101.com/r/OU4kNf/1

Comment: ^(bab|bbb)(a*b*)(a*|b*)(ba)*(aba)(bab|aba)*bb(a|b)*(bab|aba)(a|b)*$ Actualy, the spaces count! remove them and it works